# Makefile generic rule not working

Tags: gcc, makefile

I tried to make a generic makefile where you supply the names of the source files and some directories, but I can't get the generic rule for the object files to work.

My makefile is like this:

```
SOURCE_NAMES=main
EXECUTABLE_NAME=Program

EXECUTABLE_DIR=./dist
EXECUTABLE_EXT=
SOURCE_DIR=./src
SOURCE_EXT=.cc
OBJECT_DIR=./build
OBJECT_EXT=.obj

COMPILER=gcc
COMPILER_FLAGS=-c -Wall -std=gnu++11
LINKER_FLAGS=

SOURCES=$(addsuffix $(SOURCE_EXT),$(addprefix $(SOURCE_DIR)/,$(SOURCE_NAMES)))
OBJECTS=$(addsuffix $(OBJECT_EXT),$(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIR)/,$(SOURCE_NAMES)))
EXECUTABLE=$(EXECUTABLE_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)$(EXECUTABLE_EXT)

all: $(EXECUTABLE) 

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(COMPILER) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

%$(OBJECT_EXT): %$(SOURCE_EXT)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

However, the final rule, `%$(OBJECT_EXT): %$(SOURCE_EXT)`, does not seem to be working correctly, judging from the error I get:

> make: *** Er is geen regel om doel 'build/main.obj' te maken, nodig voor 'dist/RandomGenerator'.  Gestopt.

which translates to:

> make: *** There is no rule to make target 'build/main.obj', required for 'dist/RandomGenerator'.  Stopped.

When I write the rule explicitly, it does work:

```
./build/main.obj: ./src/main.cc
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

But I would rather not explicitly do that for every source file.

How do I fix this?

**Edit:**

Just for clarity, this question is about why the generic rule at the end of my makefile isn't working. I would expect `./build/main.obj` to match `%$(OBJECT_EXT)` or `%.obj`, but that doesn't seem to be the case and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Not making extensions into variables? I feel you're overdoing it a bit here...

Comment: @DevSolar What do you mean? Like simply replacing all occurences of $(OBJECT_EXT) and $(SOURCE_EXT) by .obj and .cc respectively? I already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: I cannot really make sense of what you're trying to do. For example, you added `$(SOURCES)` to the `all:` target; you might have a bright idea here, but to me it looks like a bug. I'd recommend going the opposite way: Start with a *simple* (and functional) Makefile, then work up from there. Also, [Makefile tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/Makefile).

Comment: @DevSolar On second thought I agree with you on that, so I removed that. My original idea was that it should rebuild sources if they are changed, but the way I did it was incorrect like you said it redundant since it was already implied by the dependency of the object file which isn't working. The problem hasn't been solved yet and all your remarks so far have been unrelated to the question, so I edited the question to clarify what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: There is a certain threshold of question quality at which I am reluctant to turn a question into a setup actually *reproducing* the reported problem, and instead tend to point out weaknesses in the question. Never mind, it sprang to my eyes now, answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `./build` and `./src` to your rule (which are contained in your "explicit" rule but absent from the variables you use in your Makefile).

Comment: That was it. I suspected it had something to do with the directories... Changing `%$(OBJECT_EXT): %$(SOURCE_EXT)` to `$(OBJECT_DIR)/%$(OBJECT_EXT): $(SOURCE_DIR)/%$(SOURCE_EXT)` fixed it. Could you explain why prefixing the target with the directory matters? I would expect the `%` sign to include directories.

Comment: @RPFeltz: If `%` would include directories, how could you make a rule for an object file in a direcory other than that of the source file?

Comment: Um, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that. I personally interpreted it like this: all dependencies ending in .obj should be handled by the rule specified by %.obj, independent of the directory they are in.

Comment: @RPFeltz: Then you haven't really understood how the `%` really works. The `%` on the *dependency* side of the rule gets *replaced* by the string that the `%` on the *target* side of the rule stood for. If `%.obj` would match e.g. `./build/main.obj`, then the `%.cc` on the right would be `./build/main.cc` -- and you would lose the ability to have your object file in `./build` be created from a source file in a different directory. That's why `%` does not match directory names, but only filenames (or, in practice, basenames).

Comment: I see! That makes a lot of sense then. I now understand why it didn't work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RPFeltz: You're welcome. While we're at it, try [CMake](http://www.cmake.org). It's a "Makefile creator"; effectually you really only list the source files you want to get compiled, and CMake turns this into a "all dancing, all whistling" Makefile. Or NMake file. Or Visual Studio project file. Or Eclipse CDT project. Or KDevelop project. Or MingW Makefile. Or... you get the idea. I created [JAWS](http://jaws.rootdirectory.de), a pre-configured CMake setup that handles ICU, Boost, Doxygen and LaTeX docs generation, AStyle source reformatting and style checking, continuous and nightly builds...